# How to keep the last, non-missing set of complete observations across multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal data set and would like to extract the latest, non-missing complete set of observations for each variable in the data set where id is a unique identifier, yr is year, and x1 and x2 are variables with missing values. The actual data set has 100s of variables over the course of 60 years.

```
data <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3,3)
yr=rep(1:3,times=1, each=3)
x1=c(1,3,7,NA,NA,NA,9,4,10)
x2=c(NA,NA,NA,3,9,6,NA,NA,NA))
```

Below are my expected results. For x1, the latest complete set of observations is year 3. For x2, the latest complete set of observations is year 2.

[image]

Comment: If you have some non-NAs in the year, how would you subset it

Comment: That is one of the challenges, I think. In the example above, I am selecting among sets of 3 observations (i.e. one for each unique id). If a set is not complete, it cannot be selected and we move on to the next most recent set of observations.

Comment: Something similar would be to keep the most recent value of each variable for each unique identifier rather than the most recent, complete set of identifiers.

Comment: Based on the example `subset(data, yr %in% names(tail(which(sapply(split(data[c('x1', 'x2')], data$yr), function(x) any(colSums(!is.na(x)) == nrow(x)))), 2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
subset(data, yr %in% names(tail(which(sapply(split(data[c('x1', 'x2')], 
        data$yr), function(x) any(colSums(!is.na(x)) == nrow(x)))), 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. First, I create the data frame.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3,3),
                   yr=rep(1:3,times=1, each=3),
                   x1=c(1,3,7,NA,NA,NA,9,4,10),
                   x2=c(NA,NA,NA,3,9,6,NA,NA,NA))
```

Next, I load the required libraries.

```r
# Load library
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

I then go from wide to long format, group by `yr` and `key` (i.e., variable name), remove those that have `NA` values (i.e., keep those that are **all** *not* `NA`), group by `key`, keep those data that are in the maximum year, switch back to wide format, and arrange to make the printed result look pretty.

```r
df %>% 
  gather("key", "val", x1, x2) %>% 
  group_by(yr, key) %>% 
  filter(all(!is.na(val))) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  filter(yr == max(yr)) %>% 
  spread(key, val) %>% 
  arrange(yr)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id    yr    x1    x2
#>   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2    NA     3
#> 2     2     2    NA     9
#> 3     3     2    NA     6
#> 4     1     3     9    NA
#> 5     2     3     4    NA
#> 6     3     3    10    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>